# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation licenses

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Quick question about SP 2010 licensing.
Is it totally free?

Can I install onto a web facing server without any licenses and let anybody and everybody do stuff, are there limitations??

Thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run SharePoint 2010 Foundation as an Internet Facing deployment, you will need a full SQL Server license (license per CPU) if you do not use SQL Server Express, and you will need an Internet Connection License (or Windows Server External Connector depending on what they are calling it these days - its a license which basically forgoes the need for CALs for the server and IIS) for the server you are serving from, plus standard Windows Server licenses etc.

SharePoint 2010 Foundation itself does not need a license for Internet Facing deployment, but the services it relies on does.

Comment: Thanks Moo...
so basically if I user 2010 Found with SQL Exp, its just a win 2k8 licence and thats it?? :)

Comment: No, you need to buy the External Connector license as well to license the server for outside use.

Answer (score 1):

Try hosted sharepoint solutions or BPOS (which is in WSS3.0 mode right now..) for a cheaper solution and if the requirements allow it

Answer (score 1):

The information posted above is not accurate. We have corporate licensing for Microsoft products and also run Sharepoint Foundation (although, not for long). This is directly from a MS rep in Houston, TX (Guillermo Proano). I hope he doesn't mind me quoting him here:

> 1. SharePoint Foundation 2010 for Intranet Scenarios:  you need to license Windows Server and have a Windows Server CAL for each internal user leveraging this solution.
> 2. SharePoint Foundation 2010 for Internet Scenarios: you need to license Windows Server (hosting external site) and need to purchase a Windows Server External Connector for each Windows Server in the farm running the SPS internet sites.

This is above and beyond the SQL licensing.

Comment: I'm not sure how my "inaccurate" information differs to yours?  License Windows Server?  Check.  Windows Server External Connector?  Check.  No mention of a SP2010F license?  Check (although I specifically mention you don't need to license it).  You fail to mention that you need a full SQL Server CPU license if you aren't using SQL Server Express.  So where is my information incorrect?

Comment: "You fail to mention that you need a full SQL Server CPU...". Wrong. I mentioned SQL licensing. "Sharepoint 2010 Foundation itself does not need a license for Internet Facing (sic) deployment...". Wrong. It requires a Windows Server External Connector for each Windows Server in the farm. You did not mention most products by name so people cannot use your information to generate pricing, Sergey.